# Node.js modules

Tags: windows, node.js, npm

I want to install this module: [node-poormansmysql](https://github.com/mscdex/node-poormansmysql).

My nodejs application is installed in `C:\Program Files\NodeJS\`.

I have here the folder - **node_modules**.

Here I added a folder - **node-poormansmysql**. In this folder I copied the content from github.

I still have the error - Can not find module - **node-poormansmysql**

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to copy to `C:\Users\{username}\node_modules`
Or just type in cmd `"C:\Program Files\NodeJS\npm.cmd" install node-poormansmysql`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that node will look for an index.js in the folder (or a package.json) and this library have not been packaged as a module.
So what you need to do is re-name node-poormansmysql.js to index.js
Also make sure you get all the dependencies.